# Why is this not a polynomial?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, warning-messages, polynomials

```
Subscript[x, 1] = (a x + b)/(c x + d);
CoefficientList[
 Simplify[(α + β Subscript[x, 1] + γ Subscript[x, 
       1]^2) (D[Subscript[x, 1], x]^-1)] /. a d - b c -> 1, x]
```

gives

> General::poly: "(d+c\x)^2\ (α+((b+a\x)(d\β+c\x\β+(b+a\x)\γ))/(d+c\x)^2) is not a polynomial."

This is strange, because

```
Simplify[(α + β Subscript[x, 1] + γ Subscript[x, 
      1]^2) (D[Subscript[x, 1], x]^-1)] /. a d - b c -> 1
```

always give

> `(c x+d)^2 (((a x+b) (γ (a x+b)+β c x+β d))/(c x+d)^2+α)`

which should be the more simpler version

> `(a x+b) (γ (a x+b)+β c x+β d)+α (c x+d)^2`

which is a polynomial.

BTW, how to get this question better formatted?

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have there is in the **form** of a rational function:

```
Simplify[(α + β Subscript[x, 1] + γ Subscript[x, 1]^2) (D[Subscript[x, 1], x]^-1)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you [`Expand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expand.html) and then `Simplify`, you get a polynomial.

```
Subscript[x, 1] = (a x + b)/(c x + d);
CoefficientList[
 Simplify@Expand[(α + β Subscript[x, 1] +
   γ Subscript[x, 1]^2) (D[Subscript[x, 1], x]^-1)] /. a d - b c -> 1, x]
(*
  {d^2 α + b d β + b^2 γ, 
   2 c d α + b c β + a d β + 2 a b γ, 
   c^2 α + a c β + a^2 γ}
*)
```

Checking the pieces of your computation, as in the first step above, is a good way to debug one's code.

Comment: This appears to be a weakness in `CoefficientList` since its documentation states `"CoefficientList works whether or not poly is explicitly given in expanded form."`

Comment: @BobHanlon:  I think "expanded" there means "multiplied out", which is what `Expand` does;  `Simplify` is what cancels the factors in the denominator.  Internally, `CoefficientList` probably tests for a polynomial by looking for an expression made out of `Plus` and `Power` objects the latter of which need to have positive second arguments.  (Actually, it probably just calls `PolynomialQ`, but I would imagine that the above is what that latter function does internally.)

Comment: That was great! Expand works very well.